# how to add a timeout?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

How do I add a 2h timeout to then following code in azure devops pipelines

```
pool:
    vmImage: 'ubuntu-16.04' 
steps:
    - script: docker login -u acr-p $(acrPassword) acr.azurecr.io
    - script: git clone $(gitURL)
    - script: docker build --no-cache -t acr.azurecr.io/$(imageTag) $(gitURL)
    - script: docker push acr.azurecr.io/$(imageTag)
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/customize-pipeline?view=azure-devops

```
pool:
    vmImage: 'ubuntu-16.04' 
steps:
    - script: docker login -u acr-p $(acrPassword) acr.azurecr.io
    - script: git clone $(gitURL)
    - script: docker build --no-cache -t acr.azurecr.io/$(imageTag) $(gitURL)
    - script: docker push acr.azurecr.io/$(imageTag)
```

Comment: When you need the timeout and why?

Answer (score 4):

> how to add a timeout?

You could add the parameter `timeoutInMinutes: 120` under the `- script:` to set the timeout for each script:

```
steps:
- script: string  # contents of the script to run
  timeoutInMinutes: number
```

Check the [YAML schema reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema#script) for some more details.

If you want to set the timeout for all scripts, you can add the `timeoutInMinutes` for the [job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema#job).

Hope this helps.